# Is $L = \operatorname{diag}(R\mathbf{1})-R$ a PSD matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have a dataset with $m$ feature vectors, $x_i, ~~i=1, 2, ..., m$, each of which is assigned to a partial label vector, $y_i\in\{0, 1\}^{l\times 1}, ~~i=1, 2, ..., m$. If the label $j$ is a candidate label for the sample $x_i$, then $y_{ij}=1$; otherwise  $y_{ij}=0$. So, a typical partial label vector would contain both $1$s and zeros, like this one (for $m=5$): $y_i=[0, 1, 1, 0]^T$.

Suppose we define $R=[r_{ij}]\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, where:

$r_{ij}=
  \begin{cases}
             1 &~~ \text{$y_i^Ty_j=0$} \\
             0 &~~ \text{$y_i^Ty_j\neq0$} \\
  \end{cases}$

and $L=\operatorname{diag}(R\mathbf{1}_m)-R$, where $\mathbf{1}_m$ is a $m$-dimensional vector having $1$ in every element.

Is $L$ is a positive **semi-definite (PSD) matrix**?

As I couldn't prove it analytically, I generated a lot of such matrices in Matlab and none of them had negative eigenvalues, but I'm not quite sure whether it is always PSD.

Comment: Your matrix L is evidently the graph Laplacian which is symmetric positive semidefinite.  You can compute $\mathbf x^T L \mathbf x$ equal to a sum of squares, write $L = B^T B$ with Incidence matrix B, or many other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $L$ by definition is a (weakly) diagonally dominant symmetric matrix with a nonnegative diagonal. Therefore, by [Gerschgorin disc theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), all its eigenvalues are nonnegative. Hence it is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell that how the eigenvalues are nonnegative based on the Gerschgorin disk theorem?